# random complex number

Tags: c++, random, complex-numbers

i need algorithm for generate random complex number please help i know how generate random number  but random complex number confuse me

Comment: What distribution would you like the random number to come from?

Comment: @Joey: What do you mean by an interval? Complex numbers don't have a natural ordering so don't have intervals in the same way that real numbers do.

Comment: @Joey: As do the modulus and argument, but if you do the naive thing with these you're not going to get a uniform distribution even if this is what is wanted. The point is that without knowing the required distribution it's impossible to know what the best approach is.

Comment: @Charles: The problem is probably that someone who asks how they can create a (pseudo-)random complex number won't know about the distribution as well. But you're right, I didn't think about *r* and *φ* which lead to a different result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simply generate two random numbers and use one for the real part and one for the imaginary part.

Answer (score 5):

1. Generate 2 random numbers (x, y) (use the built-in rand/rnd/random class from your environment's libraries), where `x` is the real part and `y` is the imaginary part.
2. Create a complex number class (with a constructor that takes a real and imaginary parameter)
3. Use the 2 random numbers from step 1 to create a complex number, x + *i* y

Answer (score 0):

1.Generate 2 vector of numbers say one is real_vector and another is imaginary_vector of size say MAX_SIZE to be generated randomly with differrent seeds.

2.Random shuffle the numbers in vectors(real_vector+imaginary_vector) using any distribution let us say use of std::random_shuffle(uniform distribution).

3.randomly generate a index and apply modulo operator for MAX_SIZE and select index from first array that will provide an real part of ur random number.

4.use step 3 to get imaginary part of your random number.

5.Create a complex number using number got from step 3 and step 4 and store in a container.

6.go to step 3 and check if you want any more complex number;if no then break;